The Promotion of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in Probability Theory
In probability theory, if we have $\xi$ and $\eta$ as random variables, the Cauchy Inequality can be designated as:
$$
E(\xi \eta) \leqslant \sqrt{E(\xi^2)E(\eta^2)}
$$
Then I have an idea to make an promotion of this inequality:
$$
E\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \xi_k\right) \leqslant \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n E(\xi_k^n)}\tag{1}
$$
I tried to prove this inequality by using Carlson Inequality:
$$
\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n x_k \mathrm{d}F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\right)^n \leqslant \prod_{k=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x_k^n \mathrm{d}F_k(x) 
$$
Is inequality (1) true? If so, is this a proper way to prove (1) ?

The inequality is false when $n=3, X_1=X_2\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_3=1$

Of course you have to assume that your $\xi$ are positive. Your inequality is correct and can be proved by induction on $n$ by applying the Holder inequality to $q=n+1$ and $p=(n+1)/n.$
